# Regular Expression - accents or swung dashes

Tags: .net, regex

I am using the following regex on Entity Framework data annotations:

```
    [RegularExpression("^(\\d|\\w)(\\d|\\w| |-){0}(\\d|\\w| |-)*$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "MyNameValidation", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    [Display(Name = "iFeedbackYouName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]  
    public string MyName { get; set; }
```

However it does not allow me to put text like the following examples:

*Coçar*

*Colhões*

*Cabrão*

*Caíu*

Is there any possibility to allow it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly add the non-ascii chars to the groups you want to allow them to appear in:

`^(\d|\w)(\d|\w| |-){0}([çõ]|\d|\w| |-)*$`

This also matches both sample strings using a range

`^(\d|\w)(\d|\w| |-){0}([ç-õ]|\d|\w| |-)*$`

you can also use a unicode range:

`^(\d|\w)(\d|\w| |-){0}([\u00C0-\u02af]|\d|\w| |-)*$`

Comment: But there are several combinations, It's not very practical to put all possible combinations inside my regex I guess.

Comment: @user2779312 - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by combinations. Can you provide a description of what you want to match, perhaps with some edge case examples

Comment: @user2779312 try using a unicode range or multiple ranges to cover all of the chars you're interested in.  (I added one to my answer)

Comment: Yes the unicode range is exactly what I need :) Thanks a lot (+1).